# Issue with state of toggle switch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have alraedy gone through many posts regarding the state change event of bootstrap switch.I am posting this question again as non of them helped me in solving the issue faced in my script.

I have created a toggle switch by taking inputs from the post given in the below link.
 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OzQXRm?editors=1111

I want to get the state of the switch(On/OFF) upon clicking on the switch.

I have tried the below code as suggested in many post,but this event itself is not triggered

```
$('.switch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {  
        //actions here          
    });    
</script>
```

On click event is triggered with the below code -

```
 $(document).on( 'click', 'input', function (e) { 
    //code here    
 });
```

But i am not sure how to capture the state of the toggle(on/OFF) using the above event.

Can you please help me to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: `this.checked` should work - as long as you're running under the correct event.

Comment: this what you want ? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KZQMBG?editors=1111

Comment: This is giving value as 1 irrespective of the state of the toggle.How do i get   0 or 1 based on the state of the toggle?

Comment: @SonaShetty like this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zpRKrr?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

I am able to check the state using the below code. Thanks Rory & Carsten for the input.

```
$('.switch').on('change', function (event, state) {  
  console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this code

```
   $('.status').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (event, state) {

    console.log($(this).val());
    alert(event);
    alert(state);
});
```